# Transfer dynamodb_local db file to another computer

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

We use DynamoDB for some of our stack and use Amazon's dynamodb_local instance on our dev machines. I recently upgraded to a new Macbook and have my dev environment setup correctly, however I'm unsure of how to move over the dynamodb_local database file which looks like `anything_localhost.db`, or how to use it with my new dynamodb_local instance on the new computer.

The dynamodb_local instances are both the same version (2014-10-07) and run correctly. If I specify the directory with my `anything_localhost.db` file at runtime with the `--dbPath` option, it doesn't seem to read/detect my db file.

Any help would be appreciated, and I'll edit this question with more info as needed. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just need to copy the file from a machine to the other?

Comment: Well, I copied over the file and put it in the same folder that it was running from before but the new dynamodb_local instance won't write to it. I'm using the same AWS creds from my previous computer so I'm not sure whats up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the exact same AWS credentials (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) to access the DynamoDB local database? I have noticed that each credential pair ends up creating/accessing its own DB file. Alternatively, according to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html), the -sharedDb will ensure that all credentials share the same DB.

Comment: Yes I am using the same credentials from my previous computer. Thanks for pointing out the `sharedDb` option though, I must've missed that. I'm not exactly sure though which file it was originally but I'm basing my guess on file size of the db file which was 2Mb, I had a decent amount of debugging data stored.

Comment: Did the sharedDb flag end up working for you, or are you still stuck?

Comment: Hmm looking through the dynamo logs when I run with the `dbPath` option, it IS finding the file and instantiating dynamodb_local with the file, but its not detecting any data in it. I'm gonna double check the creds are still the same..

Comment: If it is finding the file, then you must be using the right credentials and region, since the file is named: "MyAccessKeyId_Region.db". Just checking... you've looked in the file and confirmed that there is data inside?

Comment: Yaah I used [sqlitestudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/) to check `anything_localhost.db` and verified that it has my old data. Also verified I'm using the same AWS keys for this as well.

Comment: If you're using the -sharedDb flag and the same version of local, you might be able to try renaming your anything_localhost.db file to shared-local-instance.db

Comment: I made a copy of the original db file and named it `shared-local-instance.db` then fired up dynamo with the sharedDb option. It found the file, but my data is still not accessible.